# Magento 2.4 Issue with Product saleble qty

Tags: magento2.3, magento-enterprise, magento2.4, magento-cloud

I have installed Magento 2.4 enterprise edition and enabled MSI with 5 warehouse and backorder. Placed one backorder with qty 1. When i see the product saleable qty in admin it shows -5, after the second backorder it shows -10.
why does it is getting -5,-10 instead of -1,-2?